# Appendchild only appends last value from the table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a div class to different td tags, but for some reason only the last value is appended.

For debuuging purposes I created this version of the code which is working fine, its showing all the values that I want, it displays all the values inside the table in each td assigned to.

```
var td;
if(d){
  d.forEach(function(d){
    console.log(dt(d.cDD) + " cdd " + d.cDD);
    td = document.getElementById(dt(d.cDD));
    td.innerHTML += "<p>"+d.cName+"</p>";
    td.style.backgroundColor = staff(d.staff);
    console.log(staff(d.staff) + " cdd " + d.staff);
  });
}
```

However if I use the following code with appendchild, it does not work. Only the last value will be displayed on the table.

```
 var td, div;
 div = document.createElement("div");
 div.classList.add("orders_displayed");
 if(d){
   d.forEach(function(d){
     console.log(dt(d.cDD) + " cdd " + d.cDD);
     td = document.getElementById(dt(d.cDD));
     div.id = d.oID;
     div.innerHTML = d.cName;
     div.style.backgroundColor = staff(d.staff);
     td.appendChild(div);
     console.log(staff(d.staff) + " cdd " + d.staff);
     console.log(td + " " + td.id);
    });
  }
```

Is something wrong with appendchild?

Comment: since div is declared outside the forEach loop, its reference and value are updated to the last iteration of the loop. Try moving div inside the loop.

Comment: @CInvt Lol yes, i feel stupid now :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var td, div;
 div = document.createElement("div");
 div.classList.add("orders_displayed");
 if(d){
   d.forEach(function(d){
     console.log(dt(d.cDD) + " cdd " + d.cDD);
     td = document.getElementById(dt(d.cDD));
     div.id = d.oID;
     div.innerHTML += d.cName;
     div.style.backgroundColor = staff(d.staff);
     td.appendChild(div);
     console.log(staff(d.staff) + " cdd " + d.staff);
     console.log(td + " " + td.id);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I was looking for, as CInvt pointed out, i just forgot to declare div inside the loop. :)